# djangoCMS : Resources and Flow

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, django-cms

Could anyone please suggest me any flow for learning djangoCMS and any video tutorials/articles.

I have good knowledge of both python and django. I was suggested to learn the djangocms framework for my internship. When I looked into the documentation i thought it will be easy to understand. But I am not getting anything from it. I am in full confusion to understand (sometimes even when i typed the same code in documentation i am not getting the same result shown in documentation)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tutorials in the documentation, I can see that you did mention that you have already looked at these: https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/index.html.

For any inconsistencies or bugs that you find, you can raise them as a GitHub issue providing as much information as possible: https://github.com/django-cms/django-cms/issues

There are many video tutorials on the django-cms YouTube channel. Even the older ones should still work with only minor changes in django-cms 3.x versions: https://www.youtube.com/@djangocms/videos

An example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbsRVfLCE1U